# Sql query - if statement

Tags: php, sql

I try to make an "advanced" search field for users. (the users have 5-8 field to short the search list..)

I think i have to build the query depending on which posted field is not empty.

This is my original query, but with this, i got all the row from table..

```
$query = "select * from MYTABLE where FIELD1 LIKE '%$sample1%' OR FIELD2 LIKE '%$sample2%' OR FIELD3 LIKE '%$sample3%' OR FIELD4 LIKE '%$sample4%' order by name";
```

So i think i have to use IF statement in query, but i dont know how, i got error all time. And one more thing: If ths user is fill out the "sample4", then he must to fill "sample1". How can i check this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please google "SQL Injection attack'

Comment: It's not sure he's not aware of SQL injection, but I guess you're right, Mitch

Comment: What RDBMS are you coding against ?

Comment: Mitch - sql injection..i try to solve this, what alternate idea have you to do my query?
Adrian - Mysql

Comment: Read about MySQL control flow functions here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: In order understand what SQL injections are and how to avoid them (e.g. mysql_real_escape_string function), look here http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Answer (score 2):

You can also use array to do this, it will be more organized this way. For every where condition you store them in one array item, and finally join them when generating the SQL.

```
<?

$fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
// Changed this to 0, so it won't return all rows
// but also the default array element prevent the statement to fail when 
// no search is being specified at all
$wheres = array(0);
foreach ($fields as $fieldname) {
  // Get user input
  $search = $_GET[$fieldname];
  // add condition to wheres if not empty
  if (!empty($search)) {
    $wheres[] = $fieldname . ' LIKE "%' . mysql_real_escape_string($search)  . '%"';
  }
}

// Join the wheres conditions using OR, (or AND)
$query = 'select * from MYTABLE where' . join(' OR ', $wheres);

?>
```

Comment: But take care of SQL injection, as mentioned above :-)

Comment: sorry, yes, my fault I put a default 1 in the OR compare statement. Change that to 0 will do.

Comment: regarding to SQL injection, at this stage it might hinder the learning process. It is a very important issue to be aware of. You can use mysqli in PHP and use bind param method to pass in variables, when you are ready.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider implementing a "full text search" engine.

MySQL has a "FULLTEXT" search feature - you can start learning about it [here](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2003/06/26/fulltext.html):
See also this article: [Developing A Site Search Engine With PHP And MySQL](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Developing-A-Site-Search-Engine-With-PHP-And-MySQL/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to create a query that includes only the filter constraints that the user filled out, instead of including all.

If you prefer to follow your solution, you may use the SQL construct

```
CASE WHEN
```

Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx) for MS SQL and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html) for MySQL

Comment: This is exactly what i want. "reate a query that includes only the filter ..."
But i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will want a php-centric full text search solution - then look at [`Zend_Search_Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) which is a PHP port of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)
Presentations of `Zend_Search_Lucene` can be found here:

- [Roll Your Own Search Engine with Zend_Search_Lucene](http://devzone.zend.com/article/91)
- [A word on Lucene’s PHP port by Zend](http://codefury.net/2008/06/a-word-on-lucenes-php-port-by-zend/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "is not null" operator like this:

```
select * 
from mytable
where 
(field1 is not null and field1 like '%test%') or 
(field2 is not null and field2 like '%test%') or 
(field3 is not null and field3 like '%test%') or
(field4 is not null and field4 like '%test%')
order by name
```

See also [Handling MySQL NULL Values](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm)